# disable simultaneous tags editing in PHPStorm for one project

Tags: phpstorm

With latest phpStorm 9 we have new feature called simultaneous tags editing.

This is generally very nice feature that i'd like to use, but i have one old project with very bad code with a lot of mixed PHP, HTML and JS code, where it breaks code.

I know i can disable this in settings->editor->General->simultaneous tag editing, but it disables this feature for whole phpStorm. Is there way to disable it only per one project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there way to disable it only per one project?

Nope -- this is an IDE-wide setting.

---

The only possible solution I can think of is to have separate PhpStorm installation that will use custom folders to store IDE settings (look into `idea.properties` file from PhpStorm distribution, e.g. on Windows 7 it would typically be `%PhpStorm-Install-Folder%\bin\idea.properties`).

With IDE settings stored in different location you can now configure this installation with different settings (e.g. have that option turned off). *Obviously, all settings here will be different to your original setup, unless you configure it the same way or will keep certain config files synced (e.g. Keymaps, Color, Web Servers, Live Templates and other things could easily be synced on file level).*

Just remember to launch this installation when you want to work with that specific project.